# AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'chats'

Tags: telethon

Stopped working on telethon v2 how can I fix this?

`chat_list = self.client(_tl.fn.contacts.Search(q=key, limit=100)).chats`

Answer (score 0):

try;

```py
_chat_list = await self.client(_tl.fn.contacts.Search(q=key, limit=100))

chat_list = _chat_list.chats
```